# How to create my own dataset to train/test a convolutional neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

So here is my question:

I want to make my very own dataset using a motion capture camera system to get the ground truth poses and one RGB camera to get images, and then using this as input to my network, train/test a convNet.

I have looked around at other datasets for tensorflow, caffe and Matlab.  I have viewed the MNIST, Cats/Dogs, Iris, LSP, HumanEva, HumanEva3.6, FLIC, etc. datasets and have viewed and tried to understand their data as best as I can.  I have viewed online people trying to make their own datasets. The one thing is usually when you use their datasets as an example, you download a .txt file that already contains the labels.

If anyone could please explain to me how to use the image data with the labels to feed it into my network, it would be a tremendous help.  I have made code before using tensorflow to input a .txt file into the network and get the correct predicted output.  But, my brain is missing something to understand how to input an image with a label. How to I create that dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input images and your labels are two separate variables. You will be writing separate bits of code to import them. The videos typically need to be converted to JPG files (it's a royal pain to read video files directly, mostly because you can't randomly skip around the video easily).

Probably the easiest way to structure you data is via a CSV that contains filename, poseinfoA, poseinfoB, etc. And the filename refers to the JPG image on disk.

To get started on the basics, I suggest looking at the Aymericdamen tutorial examples, I haven't found tutorials anywhere that were as clear and concise.

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples

Those examples don't go into detail on the data input pipeline though. To set up a good data input pipeline in tensorflow I suggest you use the new (as of TF 1.4) Dataset object. It will force you into a good data input pipline workflow, and it's the way all data input is going in tensorflow, so it's worth learning. It's also easy to test and debug when you write it this way. Here's the guide you want to follow.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

You can start your Dataset object from the CSV, and use a `dataset.map_fn()` to load the images using `tf.image.decode_jpeg`

Since you're doing pose estimation I'll also suggest a nice blog I came across recently that will probably interest you. The topic is segmentation, but pose estimation is quite related.

http://blog.qure.ai/notes/semantic-segmentation-deep-learning-review